# Find initial vector for shell so that it hits desired target

Tags: geometry, physics

Backstory:

- We are shooting a cannon from a moving platform (e.g., a ship). Platform velocity is $p$.
- We know where our target is in relation to us (vector $t$)
- We know the velocity of our shell ($|s|$)
- We are in possession of ballistics tables that for a given gun angle and shell velocity specify how far the shell is supposed to reach (and we are very quick in searching them so we have a function $f$ that returns angle $\alpha$ such as to hit a certain distance, assuming certain shell speed)
- The shell is relatively slow-moving so the platform velocity significantly affects aim, we cannot ignore it
- We assume the target stays still
- We want to find out where to aim our cannon so that we hit the target

Variables:

- $s$ - initial vector for shell
- $p$ - platform vector for the platform that the shell is launched from ($p_y=0$)
- $t$ - vector to target ($t_y=0$, as we assume both are on the ground)
- $r$ - resulting vector for shell ($r = p+s$)

All vectors are 3D unless otherwise stated.

We are given:

- $|s|$ - initial shell velocity
- $p$ - platform vector
- $t$ - vector to target
- Function $f(|r|, d) = \alpha$ which for a given initial vector magnitude $|r|$ and distance $d$ we want to hit returns the angle $\alpha$ that hits the target

What we want to find:

- $s$ - initial shell vector

Other notes:

- Projection of $r$ onto the $xz$ plane is colinear with t (the resulting vector has to go in the direction of the target for us to hit it)

P.S. Seems simple enough, and I have been trying to solve this for a while, mainly by trying to reduce it to a 2D task by projecting it onto the plane where $r$ and $t$ vectors both lie but my vector math/geometry is too rusty.

Comment: Since you are **not** assuming parabolic motion for the projectile, do you not also require a look-up function that gives the time-of-flight for a given shell velocity and elevation angle?

Comment: You can assume that there is such a function, if it helps any. I thought for this task it is not needed, but I will introduce something like that as soon as I start predicting target position in order to lead targets.

Yes, I am not assuming parabolic motion because I plan to obtain the ballistics tables using the physics engine, simulating both air resistance and gravity. 

I don't want to convert this into a more complex problem by introducing parametric equations for shell motion, because a) I will be using the physics engine anyway and b) I thought it would make things even more complex.

Comment: This problem can be converted to the frame of reference of the platform, with a moving target, so you are already "lead(ing) targets".

Comment: I think whether I'm shooting forward or backwards compared to platform direction changes air resistance, which is quadratic to speed. So if I convert the problem like that I think I will lose some precision.

Answer (score 0):

As long as $f$ is a black box, I guess you'll have to optimize this iteratively:

1. Compute $d$ from $t$
2. Start with a reasonable guess for $\alpha$
3. Compute $s$ from $\lvert s\rvert$ and $\alpha$, using the heading from $t$
4. Compute $r$ from $s$ (and $p$)
5. Compute $\alpha$ from $r$ and $d$
6. Use the change in $\alpha$ for next iteration, starting at step 3

It might be that you can directly feed the computed $\alpha$ back into the loop. But at least for some functions $f$ that fixpoint iteration might diverge, and you might have to use e.g. bisection to actually locate the best value of $\alpha$.

If you have more details on $f$, you can improve things. If you can differentiate $f$, then you can do some optimization techniques based on gradient descent.